# Migrating a Content Types and its Nodes into another site

Tags: 7, nodes, migrations

I have 2 Drupal 7 sites and I want to migrate data from one into the other. One of the D7 sites has a bunch of content types that the other doesn't have, along with a bunch of nodes associated with it (about 1000+ nodes). It's something I can't migrate manually or else it would take forever.

I know everyone points to the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module to do something like this, but are there other similar methods that are just a streamlined. FYI, I never used the migrate module, as it seems like its more for migrating foreign data from other DB sources into drupal.

I remember there was another module that lets you copy data from another Drupal site, but it has to be the same version. Which one was this called?

Now the question is, what is the fastest approach in migrating data + content types between same version Drupal 7 sites? And what are some other caveats I might need to know?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. :) "Fastest" is a matter of opinion and every situation is unique. Have you considered [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) plus [Data Export Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import)? This might suit your circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

migrate_d2d provides a framework based on the Migrate API for migrating content from Drupal 5, Drupal 6, or Drupal 7 sites into the Drupal 7 site where it is installed

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d

Using this module you can easly migrate your content types to other d7 instance.
Here You Just need to give database link form which you want to migrating content types.

Answer (score 1):

Use [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module to capture your content types and use [node export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) module to export and import your nodes to your drupal site.